# How does 笑えない話をしていた translate to this?

Tags: verbs

I'm trying to translate a children's book myself, ハルとカナ. I got stuck on this sentence:

> ハルはリビングで、父さんと笑えない話をしていた。

Which Google translates to:

> Haru was in the living room, talking funny with his father.

The translation makes sense in context, but I can't figure out why 笑えない話 becomes "talking funny." Is it a colloquialism?

Comment: What is your own translation of 笑えない話?

Comment: This is a reminder to never ever use Google Translate as a reference for anything, no matter how simple you think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Translate made a mistake. 笑えない話 literally means "talk you can't laugh at", as you might have already guessed.

This set phrase usually refers to a scary and/or dreadful conversation, rather than just a non-comedic one.

Comment: Aha I thought it might be an idiom I wasn't familiar with. I just couldn't put the two together from first principles. So much for GT lol